# Как найти ключ по значению внутри многомерного массива

Tags: php, php7

Есть массив:

```
[ 
  'a' => [ 
   '0' => [
       '0' => [
          'value' => '1'
         ]
     ],
   '1' => [
       '0' => [
          'value' => '2'
         ]
     ]
   ],

  'b' => [ 
    '0' => [
       '0' => [
          'value' => '3'
         ]
     ],
    '1' => [
       '0' => [
          'value' => '4'
         ]
     ]
   ]
];
```

Как мне получить ключ массива, в котором у под-под массива значение value = 2 ?
То-есть 'а'.

Неужели только foreach-и делать?

Comment: Можете `array_walk` попробывать, но, имхо, `foreach` будет нагляднее и быстрее.

Comment: Да я уже сделал всё. Просто думал мало-ли. Что-то новое вдруг появилось)

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что функция "пройдись по второму уровню вложенности и верни корневой индекс в зависимости от значения" не настолько востребована, чтобы включать ее в ядро языка :D